# How to use MarkLogic xdmp:document-insert() function with 'options' argument

Tags: xquery, marklogic

When I run this example (from the documentation), I get the error:

> SEC-INVALIDPERM: `xdmp:document-insert("/example.xml", <a>aaa</a>, <options xmlns="xdmp:document-insert"><permissions><sec:permission xmlns:sec="http://marklogic.com/xdm...</options>)` -- Invalid permission

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
xdmp:document-insert(
    "/example.xml",
    <a>aaa</a>,
    <options xmlns="xdmp:document-insert">  
      <permissions>{xdmp:default-permissions()}</permissions>
      <collections>{
        <collection>/my/additional/collection</collection>,
        for $coll in xdmp:default-collections()
        return <collection>{$coll}</collection>
      }</collections>
      <quality>10</quality>
    </options>)
```

The function works if there is no options argument.

Running just `xdmp:default-permissions()` returns

```
<sec:permission xmlns:sec="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/security">
   <sec:capability>update</sec:capability>
   <sec:role-id>15080714410678341621</sec:role-id>
</sec:permission>

<sec:permission xmlns:sec="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/security">
   <sec:capability>read</sec:capability>
   <sec:role-id>15080714410678341621</sec:role-id>
</sec:permission>
```

How can I use this function with the options argument without this happening?

Comment: You xdmp:document-insert runs just fine on my end, using ML 9.0-3.1. What version are you using?

Comment: what user are you running this as? Are you sure that the role ending in 21 is still defined?

Answer (score 0):

You might be running this in MarkLogic 8 or below. This will work in MarkLogic 9 (which is the latest as of the time of writing).
The various options to `xdmp:document-insert` were separate parameters in MarkLogic 8 and below, which were aggregated into a single `options` node in MarkLogic 9.

You might want to check out the signature difference between the 2 variants:

- [xdmp:document-insert - MarkLogic 8](https://docs.marklogic.com/8.0/xdmp:document-insert)
- [xdmp:document-insert - MarkLogic 9](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:document-insert)